# Word-Break not working in Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)

Tags: css, chromium-embedded, hyphenation, word-break

I have a website that sometimes contains long words (classic german) inside a container. The page is mostly shown in an embedded browser: *either* CEF (Chromium) or WebView2 (Edge).

The problem is: the **CEF won't add hyphens to long words**. While it works on the standard Chrome browser and the embedded WebView2, the CEF will just hard break long words:

[image: cef not working]

I made sure that:

1. the page has a lang tag (in this case de-de)
2. the item has different css properties which should add hyphenation:

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
hyphens: auto;
```

Not sure whether a "working example" makes sense, since it only occurs on the CEF (and I don't know whether there is a possibility to emulate this?).

Comment: Try to set a proper user agent to CEF. Your site seems to send different CSS depending on a user agent.

Comment: @273K Thanks for the idea. Currently we are not setting any specific user agent and just take the default agent, which is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36.
Any ideas for a "proper" user agent instead of the default one?